# Why a free identifier is found even thought he wasn't defined in a function?

Tags: javascript

```
function f(){
    function f1(){
       console.log(a)
    } 
    var a =3;  
    console.log(this.hasOwnProperty("a"))
    console.log(f.hasOwnProperty("a"))
    f1();
}
f()
```

Output:

```
false
false
3
```

If JS has a lexical scope then the scope of `f1` is defined when `f1` was defined which at that time, `a` wasn't defined. Also `a` is not a property of an object, then my question is **why `f1` finds the identifier `a`?**

Comment: Google "JavaScript hoisting"

Comment: @Pointy Not (really) a hoisting issue, though - logging `a` would work with `const` too

Comment: @CertainPerformance: `const` is hoisted and just has a TDZ, no?

Comment: Yes, `const` is hoisted aswell. However, he is right, just his example is not a good one :)

Comment: *“the scope of `f1` is defined when `f1` was defined”* You can see it that way, yes, but in that case… *“at that time, `a` wasn't defined”* incorrect. `a` is declared in a scope that also contains `f1`. The position of the declaration in the function `f` doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function f(){
  function f1(){
   console.log(a)
  } 
  var a =3;  
  console.log(this.hasOwnProperty("a"))
  console.log(f.hasOwnProperty("a"))
  f1();
}
f()
```

The snippet above, will first execute function `f` and steps are as below:

1. declare variable a `//a is undefined at this step` (aka hoisting)
2. initialize the function `f1` `//not invoking at all`
3. assign 3 to variable a
4. logging both statement to be `false`
5. Invoking function `f1`
6. `f1` trying to `console.log(a)`, and variable `a` wasn't found within `f1`
7. Perform lexical chain lookup, and trying to find variable `a` at function `f`
8. Found it, print it, exit

The problem is not really with `hoisting` as pointed out by @CertainPerformance because what really happened is that, when `f1` trying to perform a `logging`, it's simply perform a lexical chain lookup to find variable `a` at function `f`

Comment: If `a` is bound to `f1` scope, doesn't it mean that one of the logs should return `true`? Why both return `false`?

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` is a method to check for property within an object, not a function. `a` is a local variable in function `f`, not a property of it

Comment: For more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty